# Vue component and datatypes props

Tags: vue.js, datatables, components

I'm trying to create a vue component to all my datagrids, I'm using DataTables library (https://datatables.net/), so, i've already create my vue component:

**GridDatos.vue**

```
<template>
<div class="container">
    <h4>{{titulo}}</h4>
    <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered nowrap" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th v-for="col in colNames">{{col}}</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>sssss</td>
                <td>sssss</td>
                <td>sssss</td>
                <td>sssss</td>
                <td>sssss</td>
                <td>sssss</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th v-for="col in colNames">{{col}}</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
</div>
```

**The instance:**

```
Vue.component('grid-datos', require('./components/GridDatos.vue').default);
```

**And the usage:**

```
<div id="app">
        <grid-datos 
            url="/api/listadoContactos" 
            titulo="Mis Datos" 
            :col-names="('Name','Position','Office','Age','Start date','Salary')">
        </grid-datos>
    </div>
```

But the problem here is the table header, it seems to use the last array element as you can see in the screenshot:

[Titles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91FrZ.png)

Definitely i'm not setting the array correctly when call the component.
Could anybody help me?

Thanks a lot. Regards.

Comment: It´s solved, using :col-names="['Name','Position','Office','Age','Start date','Salary']"

Comment: datatables.net is a jQuery plugin and is probably not ideal for Vue

Comment: Thank you Flame, in your experience what do you suggest? I'm new in this tools. Thanks.

Comment: ive been using https://www.vuetable.com/ which works pretty good, but has some odd functionality as well. You could also create your own datatable depending on your requirements, but you need to have done some Vue in order to create a plan for such thing. But in essence you shouldnt really need anything related to jQuery since that requires the whole jquery library to be loaded. It CAN be used but doesnt really suit the vue reactivity.

Comment: I'll consider your comment. Thank you.